# ConvertRect returning wrong rect reference

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiview

```
UIView *sourceView = self.sourceImagesContainerView.subviews[self.currentImageIndex];
UIView *parentView = [self getParsentView:sourceView];
CGRect rect = [sourceView.superview convertRect:sourceView.frame toView:parentView];
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(rect));
```

Used in tableView to get the position of the imageView to the other view, but when I slide tableView, the rect is wrong.

I don't know how to deal with this.

Comment: What a terrible title!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a tableView as a parent for this transformation unless you are prepared to subtract the contentOffset.

```
UIView *sourceView = self.sourceImagesContainerView.subviews[self.currentImageIndex];
UITableView *parentView = self.tableView;
CGRect rect = [sourceView.superview convertRect:sourceView.frame toView:parentView];
rect = CGRectOffset(rect, 0-parentView.contentOffset.x, 0-parentView.contentOffset.y);
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(rect));
```

Better to use a non scrolling parent:

```
UIView *sourceView = self.sourceImagesContainerView.subviews[self.currentImageIndex];
UIView *parentView = self.navigationController.view;
CGRect rect = [sourceView.superview convertRect:sourceView.frame toView:parentView];
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(rect));
```